# Filtering an ASP.NET ObjectDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, webforms, objectdatasource

I have a ObjectDataSource in a standard ASP.NET WebForm which allows effective paging by only loading the data required for the page the user is viewing. I now want to filter the results on specific columns (say column Customer), how would you go about this?

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ticketsDataSource" runat="server"
        SelectMethod="GetTicketsData" EnablePaging="true"
        MaximumRowsParameterName="pageSize"
        StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex"
        TypeName="SupportSystem.App_Code.TicketsDataSource" SelectCountMethod="TotalRowCount">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="startRowIndex" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="pageSize" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I was previously doing everything in code behind as follows, but this meant once numerous tickets were added, the grid was **very** slow when paging etc as it was loading all the data before rendering etc.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
d.Add("@params", "");
ds.ReadXml(new System.IO.StringReader(Database.DAL_XML("Usp_Fetch_Tickets", d).OuterXml));
if (Database_error(ds))
{
   return;
}
var dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "Customer LIKE '%abc%'";
var newDS = new DataSet();
var newDT = dv.ToTable();
newDS.Tables.Add(newDT);
gvTickets.DataSource = newDS;
gvTickets.DataBind();
```

Any ideas of how to effectively filter the ObjectDataSource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi You can use `FilterExpression` for that purpose. Following is the sample snippet how to achieve that.

```
<asp:objectdatasource
          id="ObjectDataSource1"
          runat="server"
          selectmethod="GetAllEmployeesAsDataSet"
          typename="Samples.AspNet.CS.EmployeeLogic"
          filterexpression="FullName='{0}'" OnFiltering="ObjectDataSource1_Filtering">
            <filterparameters>
              <asp:formparameter name="FullName" formfield="Textbox1" defaultvalue="Nancy Davolio" />
            </filterparameters>
        </asp:objectdatasource>
```

Additional info can be found on the following msdn page
[check this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.filterexpression(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this looks great and if I wanted multiple filters I can use {1} {2} etc and specify more asp:formparameter?

Comment: Isn't this subject to Sql Injection ?
Is there a way to user filters with safe parameters (using @myparam...) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FilterParameters` property from markup and then specify one of the `Parameter` sub classes. For example, suppose you have a `TextBox` that you provide the user to input a customer name to filter the results by that customer, you will need to use a `ControlParameter` for this...

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource>
      <FilterParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtCustomer" PropertyName="Text" Name="customerName" />
      </FilterParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

here `txtCustomer` would be the ID of the `TextBox`, `Text` is the property of that control to get the input value from and `customerName` is a parameter in the `GetTicketsData` method that you need to expose in order to pass in the filter value